# Replacing the block of code with the new Code

Tags: eclipse

I am having a block of code in Eclipse IDE and I want to replace that with new block of code in the whole project, can any one help me out regarding this issue.

Comment: i dont use eclipse but i image it has find / replace ? as a side note repeated code is bad practice for this reason - consider refactoring to a single function

Answer (score 0):

First consider to refactor the repeated code into a **function** and then you can easily find/replace the function name. It will save you a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

If its just one line of code, just click ctrl+H select the so it should search in your project, when eclipse finds all results right click on the search window and select "replace all".

If its more than one line of code, enable first regular expression search, so when you select the code and hit ctrl+H eclipse will convert your text to regex, then do the search and select replace all...

(in the search window, make sure to be in the "File Search" tab.)